# When upgrading a WSP file using a C# code receive an error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

There are several WSPs that I am trying to install, all of which were upgraded properly in SP2013 environment, but when I am trying to upgrade them in SP2016 then it is not working.

I am using a command of **Solution.Upgrade** to upgrade them.

Here's the error message received:

> **Type:    Core Solution
>
>   Contains Web Application Resource:  No
>
>   Contains Global Assembly:   Yes
>
>   Contains Code Access Security Policy:   No
>
>   Deployment Server Type: Front-end Web server
>
>   Deployment Status:  Error
>
>   Deployed To:    Globally deployed.
>
>   Last Operation Result:  Some of the files failed to copy during deployment of the solution.
>
>   Last Operation Details:  The solution has not been upgraded.
>
>   Last Operation Time:    5/17/2017 5:23 AM**

Can any one tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue by seeing the logs carefully. While looking in to the logs I have found out that due to some reason Timer Service is stopped before my Upgrade code is run. So put a code to check the timer service status and if it is stopped then I started it again.

If you don't want to check for the stopped service. you can simply stop the service and start it again.

This hack has resolved my issue and now every wsp is deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you retract the solution and deploy again? Try this if you have not.

How did you migrated your SP2013 sites to SP2016. Was it through powershell backup and restore command? There can be version conflict. So, try to migrate your site using database backup and restore.

Also, use Visual Studio 2015 to rebuild your solution and then deploy it. VS2015 has SP2016 templates. Take target framework 4.5 or above.

Comment: YEs it worked if I retract remove and add then deploy solution. THis are the wsps created which are common for SP2010 and SP 2013. I want to deploy it to 2016 as well